# boost::asio::error class no longer exists

Tags: c++, boost

I was using C++ Boost library 1.34.0; now I am going to use Boost 1.55.0. However, `boost::asio::error` class no longer exists in this version.

What is the replacement for `boost::asio::error` class? Should I use `boost::system::error_code` class instead?

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside for a moment that [*Boost.Asio* was not actually introduced until Boost 1.35.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/) (so you cannot possibly have been using it in Boost 1.34.0), `boost::asio::error` *never* existed as a class; [it was a namespace in 1.35.0 containing a set of enums](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/asio/error.hpp), and [they're all still there today](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html).

So you do not need to change anything.